# replace() function not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a js replace function to replace text next to two radio buttons on a pre set form.

Script is as follows.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    "Payment by <b>Moneybookers</b> e-wallet<br>", ""
);
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    "Maestro, Visa and other credit/debit cards by <b>Moneybookers</b>",
    "Pago con Diners Club, Mastercard o Visa"
);
```

The script works fine in Chrome and Firefox, however, the script is not actioned in Explorer.

I believe it has something to do with there being , `/  -` within the text I am replacing? When I use the function to replace text with no , `/ -` in the text - it works fine in explorer, however, for example when I try to replace text.. - "Maestro, Visa and other credit/debit cards by Moneybookers" this does not work in explorer.. I'm assuming because of the coma and forward slash. Honestly I've tried everything but just can not get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried escaping the / (ie \/) and the , (ie \,) ?

Answer (score 3):

Try it with a regular expression:

```
.replace(/Payment by <b>Moneybookers<\/b> e-wallet<br>/, "")
```

If that doesn't work, try making it case insensitive. Internet Explorer might be converting the tags to upper case.

```
.replace(/Payment by <b>Moneybookers<\/b> e-wallet<br>/i, "")
```

On a different point, replacing the entire body's innerHTML probably isn't a great idea. Every DOM element in the page would be destroyed, the new HTML re-parsed and then new elements created. Perhaps try to narrow down your replacement to the element which actually contains this text.

Comment: Hey Nick, Thanks for your time, however, no luck with any of the suggested changes, still works fine in chrome and firefox with the changes, however, still no change with explorer.

Comment: @LEOPM Ok, try double-checking what the value of the innerHTML property is to make sure it's what you expect. If you could also try narrowing down the problem to a short example which demonstrates it, perhaps we could go from there

Answer (score 0):

I recently fixed a bug that might help.

If your value that you were replacing was 0 -- as a value, not a string -- IE11 would only append the replacement string instead of actually replacing it.

Here's what I was working with:

```
buf = buf.replace( /%%TOTALAMOUNT%%/gim, "$" + parseFloat( g_UserPurchases[LCV].CurrencyValue.val() ).toFixed(2) );
```

This printed: "**%%TOTALAMOUNT%%.00**"

I fixed it by checking:

```
if( ( g_UserPurchases[LCV].CurrencyValue.val() == 0 ) || ( g_UserPurchases[LCV].CurrencyValue.val() === 0 ) ){
//IE fix: IE did not like the $ character and didn't replace if val = 0
buf = buf.replace( /%%TOTALAMOUNT%%/gim, "&#36;0.00");    }
```

Please note: IE11 didn't replace the the dollar sign character, $. So, I used the character code instead:

```
&#36;
```

Hope this helps!